# How can I send multiple images to a flask server?

Tags: python, flask, python-requests

I need to send this dictionary with the requests.post method with the file parameter, to a flask server this dictionary contains the names of the images that I want to save and then display

```
dd = {
'img' : ['a.jpg','b.jpg','c.jpg','d.jpg','e.jpg']
}
```

This is my client script that sends the images

```
import requests as RQ

dd = {
    'img' : ['a.jpg','b.jpg','c.jpg','d.jpg','e.jpg']
}

url = 'http://127.0.0.1:/8070/img_d'

#convierto el diccionario en una tupla   
mul_img = []
for v, k in enumerate(dd):
    a = dd.get(k)
    for i in a:
        mul_img.append((k, open(i, 'rb')))

Res = RQ.post(url, files=mul_img)

Res.text
```

and this is the flask server that works

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request, render_template, redirect, url_for, send_from_directory
#from app import Res



app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER']= "./img"


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")
    



#@app.route('/img_d', methods=['POST'])
#def i():
 #   return jsonify(Res)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, port=8070)
```

The problem I have is that when I comment the lines I get an error

```
from app import Res  
@app.route('/img_d', methods=['POST'])
def i():
    return jsonify(Res)
```

The error when I run the flask script

> requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
> HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=80): Max retries exceeded
> with url: /8070/img_d (Caused by
> NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at
> 0x000001AB457DC6A0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError
> 10061] No se puede establecer una conexión ya que el equipo de destino
> denegó expresamente dicha conexión'))

I don't really know what's going on and I would like if it wasn't a nuisance to explain to me what I'm doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

From official documentation, try this.

```
multiple_files = [
    ('images', ('foo.png', open('foo.png', 'rb'), 'image/png')),
    ('images', ('bar.png', open('bar.png', 'rb'), 'image/png'))]
r = requests.post(url, files=multiple_files)
```